# scp gives "not a regular file"

Tags: linux, scp

I have a problem when using scp on Linux, it says "not a regular file". I looked at other questions/answers about that, but I can't find out what's wrong...
I wrote:

```
scp aa@aa:/home/pictures/file.fits .
```

to copy `file.fits` from `aa@aa`, `/home/pictures` to the current directory. I also tried without using `/home/`, but it didn't work neither...

Do you understand what's wrong?

Comment: Try: `scp aa@aa:~/pictures/file.fits .`

Comment: maybe the path is wrong and should contain your Linux user name. /home/<user>/pictures maybe?

Comment: Tilda will be your best friend in this case :). Don't extend your directory path in this case. And now that I am thinking of it, your command wont work anyways. If you were to add the whole directory, it would look something like: `scp aa@aa:/home/aa/pictures/file.fits .`

Comment: Log in with ssh (`ssh aa@aa`) and give command: `file /home/pictures/file.fits` and tell us what that says.

Comment: It will save you time and effort just by switching to `rsync`. Use `rsync -azHvu aa@aa:/home/pictures/file.fits .`. This will allow rsync to copy recursively and follow symlinks and show (verbose) what it is copying.

Comment: if it is a folder try to use ```-r``` flag, it worked on my case.

Comment: ```sudo scp -r -P 4444 folder/ admin@144.15.13.21:~/Downloads```

Answer (score 109):

I just tested this and found at least 3 situations in which scp will return `not a regular file`:

1. File is actually a directory
2. File is a named pipe (a.k.a. FIFO)
3. File is a device file

Case #1 seems most likely. If you meant to transfer an entire directory structure with `scp` use the `-r` option to indicate recursive copy.

Comment: It also occurs if you're not awake yet and you have your source and destination inverted and you're trying to copy a non-existent file from your destination to your source...

Comment: This implies reading stdin and writing stdout as in `sftp -b <(echo get file /dev/fd/1)`

Comment: I am facing the issue with symlinks too.

Comment: I'm trying to handle second case(in fact, I try to copy physical disk(like `/dev/sda` but actual name is a bit different. possible solution is to pipe disk to fifo then scp it to my host)

Answer (score 31):

"/home/pictures/file.fits" must name an actual filesystem object on the remote server. If it didn't, `scp` would have given a different error message.

I see that FITS is [an image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS). I suppose "/home/pictures/file.fits" is the name of a directory on the remote server, containing FITS files or something like that.

To copy a directory with `scp`, you have to supply the "-r" flag:

```
scp -r aa@aa:/home/pictures/file.fits .
```

Comment: This really helped me `To copy a directory with scp, you have to supply the "-r" flag`

Comment: This resolved a problem I was having where trying to scp a UTM virtual machine file...or so I thought.  .utm is a directory so I needed the '-r'.

Answer (score 13):

**One way this error can occur is if you have a space before the first path like below:**

```
scp myUserName@HostName: /path/to/file  /path/to/new/file                            ^
```

**To fix, just take the space out:**

```
scp myUserName@HostName:/path/to/file  /path/to/new/file
```

Answer (score 7):

By being teaching lots of people of basic sysadmin I must say in 90% cases it is because they are trying to copy directory without passing `-r` [source](https://hinty.io/devforth/scp-not-a-regular-file-how-to-fix/)

Just use -r flag. E.g to copy from remote to local:

```
scp -r root@IP:/path/on/server/ /path/on/local/pc
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that you are working with a directory/folder.

If this is the case, here is what you want to do:

1. First, compress the folder. By running the command:

   **zip -r name_of_folder.zip name_of_folder**
2. Then use the scp command normally to copy the file to your destination:

   **scp path/to/name_of_folder.zip server:localhost:/path/to/name_of_folder.zip**
3. Enter your password if it prompts you for one.
4. Unzip the name_of_folder.zip with this command:

   **unzip name_of_folder.zip**

That is it, you now have your folder in the destination system. By the way, this is for zip compression.

NOTE: If you are on Mac OS and you don't want to see resource files such as _MACOSX, you may run:

```
**zip -r -X name_of_folder.zip name_of_folder**
```

Meaning the above command should be used instead of that in step 1 above.

Answer (score 4):

simple steps you need to follow

1)scp -r user@host:/var/www/html/projectFolder /var/www/html/localsystem-project-folder

2)scp -r user@host:/var/www/html/projectFolder/filename.php /var/www/html/localsystem-project-folder/

here -r is for recursive traverse the director will help you without any error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recursive (-r) flag to copy the files.

```
get -r folderName
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work because you need the precise the name of copied file ;
So use this command like this :

```
scp aa@aa:/home/pictures/file.fits ./file.fits
```

You can rename your file too like this :

```
scp aa@aa:/home/pictures/file.fits ./newNameFile.fits
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the destination can be a folder.

Answer (score -1):

The below command worked for me
scp -ri -P port source destination